# Why doesn't this setup work for a foreign key relationship in JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to set up a foreign key relationship with [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) annotations and generate the tables using [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29), but I get an error and can't see the reason for it. I execute the main method in User to generate the tables.

Here's the error -

```
INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type    for: com.site.model.Name, at table: USER, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(name)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:306)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlTypeCode(Column.java:164)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:208)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.sqlCreateString(Table.java:418)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateSchemaCreationScript(Configuration.java:1099)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:131)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:92)
at com.thepoliticalbottomline.model.User.main(User.java:55)
```

And the source code,

```
package com.sitename.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;

@Entity
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String password;
    private Name name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setName(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Name getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(Name.class);
        config.configure();
        new SchemaExport(config).create(true, true);
    }
}
```

Class Name,

```
package com.sitename.model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Name {
    private Long id;
    private String first;
    private String middle;
    private String last;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
    * @param id the id to set
    */
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the first
     */
    public String getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    /**
     * @param first the first to set
     */
    public void setFirst(String first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    /**
     * @return the middle
     */
    public String getMiddle() {
        return middle;
    }

    /**
     * @param middle the middle to set
     */
    public void setMiddle(String middle) {
        this.middle = middle;
    }

    /**
     * @return the last
     */
    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    /**
     * @param last the last to set
     */
    public void setLast(String last) {
        this.last = last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix JPA annotations on attributes and methods. You can only annotate attributes **or** methodos in a given class.

This applies to Hibernate. I'm not sure about other JPA implementations.